# If $S$ is non-empty subset of the vector space $V$, then $span \{S\}$ is a subspace of the vector space V. Why?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Proposition** Let $S$ be non-empty subset of the vector space $V$. The set $span\{S\}$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$.

I'm assuming that this proposition is correct, but I don't understand why.

To show you what I mean, let's consider an example.

Let $V$ be vector space, where

$$V = \{(a,b,0)^{T} \mid a,b \in \mathbb R\}$$

---

The addition of the vectors is defined as

$$\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} = (a,b,c)^{T} + (e,f,g)^{T} = (a+e, b+f,c+g)^{T}$$

And scalar multiplication as:

$$k \mathbf{x} = k\cdot(a,b,c)^{T} = (ka,kb,kc)^{T}$$

---

Now consider subspace $S$:

$$S = \{(a,0,0)^{T} \mid a\in \mathbb R\}$$

Suppose we have vectors $\bf v_{1}$ and $\bf v_{2}$ such that

$$\mathbf {v_{1}} = (1,0,0)^{T}$$

and

$$\mathbf {v_{2}} = (1,1,1)^{T}$$

Consider linear combination 
$$\tag ! k_{1}\mathbf{v_{1}} + k_{2}\mathbf{v_{2}} = \bf u$$

Where $\bf u$ is arbitrary vector in the subspace $S$. We see that, provided that $k_{2} = 0$, *any* vector in $S$ can be rewritten as the linear combination $(!)$, or in other words, vectors $\bf v_{1},v_{2}$ *span* set $S$. However, at the same time, $\bf v_{2}$ *is not* in $V$, hence proposition fails.

---

I assume there is some flaw in my reasoning, but where exactly?

Comment: What is your precise definition of “span”? There are two basic ways of doing it, and in one of them the fact that it is a subspace is almost immediate.

Comment: As to you reasoning, $\mathbf{v}_2\notin V$ so $S=\{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2\}$ is not a subset of $V$.

Comment: @Arturo Quote from the same book where proposition was given : If every vector in $V$ can be produced by a linear combination of vectors $\mathbf {v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3},... }\text{ and } \bf v_{n}$ then these vectors span or generate the vector space V. We write this as $span${$\bf v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3},..., v_{n}$}. But there is *no* mentioning that vectors $\bf v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3},..., v_{n}$ *must* be in $V$

Comment: @Neiver: That is not the definition of “span of a subset $S$”. That is the definition of “a subset $S$ spans $V$”. Not the same thing.

Comment: @Nevier: You are looking at the wrong definition. And that quote/definition does not even make sense *unless* the vectors are in $V$. In any case, this particular proposition **explicitly** requires $S$ to be “**a non-empty subset of $V$**”, so regardless of what you are not finding in your textbook, this proposition **is** about subsets and only about subsets.

Comment: @Arturo, this is apparently what I'm missing. What I had thought was, for example, if we had vectors $\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ such that these vectors *span* $S$ (and $S$ is the subset of $V$), then vectors $\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ would *not necessarily* be in $V$. I suppose this reasoning is wrong?

Comment: It’s not even reasoning: it’s a misunderstanding of what the definition says. It is also a misunderstanding of how that definition relates to this question. Let me be clear and explicit again. “The span of a subset $S$ of $V$” is one thing. Saying “A subset $S$ of $V$ spans $V$” is a **different** (though related) thing. You are quoting one definition, but that definition is not what this proposition is even about!

Comment: @Arturo, still being confused, I will try to approach this from different side. Suppose we have some vector space, call it $A$. Now suppose we have some vectors, $\bf u_{1},u_{2},\cdots,u_{n}$ such that *every* vector in $A$ can be produced by linear combination of the vectors $\bf u_{1},u_{2},\cdots,u_{n}$. Will these vectors *necessarily* be in the vector space $A$? Or there is a possibility that *at least one* one vector, call it $\bf u_{j}$, won't be in $A$?

Comment: You need context. Is $A$ the only vector space in play, or is it a subset of a larger set? Also, do you call the set a "spanning set of $A$", or do you just ask whether every vector in $A$ can be obtained? This is important!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{v_1,v_2\}$ is not a subset of your vector space $V$, or your subspace $S$, as required by the proposition, and presumably your definition of span (since $v_2\notin V$ and $v_2\notin S$). Thus their span is not a subset and therefore not a subspace.

It doesn't matter that $S, V, v_1$ and $v_2$ are all part of a bigger vector space $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Arthur, seems like now I'm getting it, but I would like you to verify whether my understanding is correct. Suppose we have set $S = \{(1,2,3)^{T}, (23,1,-3)^{T}\}$ So $span\{S\}$is the  set that consists of all vectors that can be written as linear combination of $(1,2,3)^{T}$ and  $(23,1,-3)^{T}$. Is it correct?

Comment: @Nelver Yes, that's correct. And since $S$ is a subset of, for instance, the vector space $\Bbb R^3$, we get that $\operatorname{Span}(S)$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ from the proposition.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be greatly confused on a couple of concepts:

1. Spanning set of a vector space.
2. The span of a subset of a vector space.

Let $\mathbf{V}$ be a vector space; and let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbf{V}$. We say that $S$ is a **spanning set of $\mathbf{V}$** if every vector in $\mathbf{V}$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $S$.

Note that to say "spanning set of $\mathbf{V}$", the set must be a subset of $\mathbf{V}$.

On the other hand, let $\mathbf{W}$ be a vector space, and let $T$ be a subset of $\mathbf{W}$. **The span of $T$** is the set
$$\mathrm{span}(T) = \{ \mathbf{w}\in\mathbf{W}\mid \mathbf{w}\text{ is a linear combination of elements of }T\}.$$

Now, the theorem at hand shows that $\mathrm{span}(T)$ is in fact a subspace of the vector space $\mathbf{W}$. One can show more: $\mathrm{span}(T)$ is the *smallest* subspace of $\mathbf{W}$ that contains $T$, in the following sense: if $\mathbf{Y}$ is *any* subspace of $\mathbf{W}$ that contains $T$, then $\mathrm{span}(T)\subseteq \mathbf{Y}$.

With these definitions, a subset $S$ of a vector space $\mathbf{V}$ spans $\mathbf{V}$ if and only if $\mathrm{span}(S) = \mathbf{V}$.

Now, you seem to be confused about whether a spanning set must be a subset of your vector space. Let me dispel that confusion: **YES**; a spanning set **must** be a subset of the vector space in question.

Your formulation, where you do not require the set to be contained in your space, is not useful; note that if $\mathbf{V}$ is a vector space, and $S$ is a spanning set for $\mathbf{V}$, then it true that every vector in $\mathbf{V}$ is a linear combination of elements of $S$. But then, if you take a *proper* subspace $\mathbf{W}$ of $\mathbf{V}$, then of course every vector in $\mathbf{W}$ is also a linear combination of elements of $S$ (say, if you have a set that you can use to get any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then you can also use the set to get every vector on the $xy$-plane, $\mathbf{W}=\{(a,b,0)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$. But that is not useful because that means going "outside" of $\mathbf{W}$.